# How to protect a resource (html page)from directly accessing without login in

Tags: jersey

I have a set of HTML pages namely

login.html , 
CreateNewLocation.html ,
CreateNewVendor.html ,
AdminApprove.html

and some more html pages

I am using jersey REST Framework for my APplication .

How can i restrict user from directly accessing the page

http:localhost:8080/local/CreateNewLocation.html

without directly logging in through login.html ??

Answer (score 0):

No way. You have to "convert" (rename) html files to PHP and add session check at the beginning.